# Unable to upload files using Google Drive API in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I want to upload files from my local folder to Google Drive using Google Drive API in Python.

Currently, I am facing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\ice\projects\testproject\googledrive_api.py", line 72, in <module>
    service.files().create(
  File "C:\Users\ice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 134, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 915, in 
execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?fields=id&alt=json&uploadType=multipart returned "File not found: 18JvVkD3wy79bZ039viXEt1J2AP3f5Iqm.">
```

Here are my codes:

```
import os
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from Google import Create_Service
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

# Authentication and list files in Google Drive
gauth = GoogleAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

fileList = drive.ListFile(
    {'q': "'1Gnv3rIbBG1-xwtk6PIidqB02XkeoUEvc' in parents and trashed=false"}).GetList()
for file1 in fileList:
    print('title: %s, id: %s' % (file1['title'], file1['id']))

# Upload file(s) to Google Drive
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secrets.json'
API_NAME = 'drive'
API_VERSION = 'v3'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)

# ID of the destination folder
folder_id = '18JvVkD3wy79bZ039viXEt1J2AP3f5Iqm'

# 1st list for file names, 2nd list for file types
file_names = ['age.pdf', 'age.png']
mime_types = ['application/pdf', 'image/png']

for file_name, mime_type in zip(file_names, mime_types):
    file_metadata = {
        'name': file_name, 
        'parents': [folder_id]
    }

    media = MediaFileUpload('./{0}'.format(file_name), mimetype=mime_type)

    service.files().create(
        body=file_metadata,
        media_body=media,
        fields='id'
    ).execute()
```

I really can't figure out how to solve this issue. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: This is probably because either you are not getting the right folder ID or you are not using the right token (an authorization problem). Were you able to list your files correctly? Could you try removing your token and run again the script to get a new token to make sure that was not the issue? Is the parent folder in a shared Drive or in your normal Drive?

Answer (score 1):

Use this ***supportsTeamDrives=True*** param in create function

Like this

```
service.files().create(
        supportsTeamDrives=True,
        body=file_metadata,
        media_body=media,
        fields='id'
    ).execute()
```

Comment: Wow. This problem had me stuck for ages ! Thanks so much. Incidentally, in Java, this is setSupportsAllDrives(true) in the latest API.